# How to define the path that Azure WebApp uses as a warmup request without using IIS config?

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed my application as a docker container, so I don't really use the IIS provided on Azure WebApp.

Looking at the docs I found on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#specify-custom-warm-up that you can set up the environment variable `WEBSITE_SWAP_WARMUP_PING_PATH` so I can customize it during a swap operation. But is this possible also for the normal operation?

Answer (score 0):

By normal operation, I assume you mean a deployment directly to the web app, not any slots. The cmdlet that you mentioned simply sends an HTTP request to the path you specify within the web app.

Assuming that you're using a deployment tool such as VSTS or Azure Pipelines, you should be able to create a deployment task to either ping the root of your site (assuming you don't have authentication in place) or something like the below powershell script to ping a destination folder.

```
<Target Name="CopyDeployScriptToPackageFolder" AfterTargets="Package">
<Copy SourceFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\deployment\warm-up.ps1" DestinationFolder="$(PackageLocation)" />
```

[More info](https://www.finai.com/en/newsroom/how-to-deploy-warm-up-an-application-in-azure-using-vsts/)

Comment: No. It’s not what I mean. My container does not answer to the / path, so with always on mode I get a log full of 404 errors due to the “always on” requests. I don’t need to have a warmup request. Just need to change this path because the docker deployment in the WebApp uses this right after deployment and during the life of it.

Comment: So for none container web apps, the below link is normally the process. You'd use a URL rewrite to direct the path of the ping to the appropriate location. Wit that being said, is it possible for you to place a web.config file outside your container and rewrite the URL to inside your container? Otherwise, you'll need to likely develop a custom ping solution such as an Azure Function that runs a powershell script tcpping cmlet every 5 minutes to your container. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/benjaminperkins/how-to-optimize-azure-app-service-alwayson-cold-start-warm-up-request

Comment: @BryanTrach-MSFT are you saying there's no way to change the 'always on' ping path for container app services? This may be tangentially related to the OP, but I'm getting a steady stream of 404 failures to `GET /` that appear to be that probe.